# Auto ML always returns "Training pipeline failed with error message: Train set should contain all labels."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've been trying to train a classification model on about 300k rows of data. I've triple checked none of the columns are null, but I always get an error message after about 10 minutes:

`Training pipeline failed with error message: Train set should contain all labels.`

Maybe I am misunderstanding the error message, what are some likely causes of it?